# Direct Product Subgroups

Tags: group-theory

My lecturer gave us a warning and I'm not sure I understand it:

"A subgroup of A x B need not be a direct product A1 x B1"

He gave us this example:

A = C4 = < a >

B = C2 < b >

< (a,b) > <= A x B

= {(a,b), (a^2, 1), (a^3, b), (1,1)}

Which he says is not a direct product, but I don't understand this. Is this not just A1 x B1 where A1 = C4 and B1 = C2? Why is this not a direct product?

Comment: The direct product you describe has order $8$; this subgroup has order $4$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

The direct product of $C_4$ and $C_2$, in your notation, consists of the following elements:

$$ \{(1,1), (a,1), (a^2,1), (a^3,1), (1,b), (a,b), (a^2,b), (a^3,b)\}. $$

While the subgroup you mention has the following elements:

$$ \{(1,1), (a,b), (a^2,1), (a^3,b)\}. $$